# how to play sound file using FMOD sdk?

Tags: iphone

I want to implement playing sound file using FMOD sdk in iphone.
I know this is third party tool but i want to implement playback speed.So only possible in FMOD.So please help me.

Answer (score 0):

System::createSound to create a FMOD::Sound object.
System::playSound to play that Sound on a FMOD::Channel
Channel::setFrequency to adjust the playback speed

Optionally:
Channel::addDSP to attach a pitch shift DSP to compensate for pitch change